# Why the range slider is init to value 0 even if i set it's minimum to 1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
[Range(1, 100)]
public int InstantiateObjectsPositionX = 1, InstantiateObjectsPositionY = 1, InstantiateObjectsPositionZ = 1;
```

In the inspector all the 3 sliders are at value 0. Why they are not at value 1 ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class GenerateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectPrefab;

    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int numberOfObjects = 1;
    public int maxDepth;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int posX = 1, posY = 1, posZ = 1;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int numberOfChildrenInLevel = 1;
    public bool randomNumberOfChildren = false;

    private GameObject parent;
    private int count = 0;
    private int oldNumberOfObjects;
    private int currentDepth;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        oldNumberOfObjects = numberOfObjects;

        parent = GameObject.Find("Generate Objects");

        StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (oldNumberOfObjects != numberOfObjects)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
            oldNumberOfObjects = numberOfObjects;
        }
        else
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

            if (objectPrefab != null)
            {
                GameObject go = InstantiateObjects(parent.transform);
                go.tag = "Instantiated Object";
                GenerateChildren(go);
            }

            count++;

            if (count == numberOfObjects)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    GameObject child;
    private void GenerateChildren(GameObject go)
    {
        if (currentDepth < maxDepth)
        {
            if (randomNumberOfChildren)
            {
                int ggg = Random.Range(1, numberOfChildrenInLevel);
                numberOfChildrenInLevel = ggg;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildrenInLevel; i++)
            {
                child = InstantiateObjects(null);
                child.transform.parent = go.transform;
            }

            currentDepth++;
            GenerateChildren(child);
        }
        else
        {
            currentDepth = 0;
        }
    }

    private GameObject InstantiateObjects(Transform parent)
    {
        return Instantiate(objectPrefab,
            new Vector3(Random.Range(0, posX), Random.Range(0, posY), Random.Range(0, posZ)),
            Quaternion.identity, parent);
    }

    public void ClearObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] instantiatedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Instantiated Object");
        foreach (GameObject go in instantiatedObjects)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(go);
        }
    }
}
```

The result :

[image: ranges]

Only if i will click now on the sliders and drag them then the slider it self will show and only then i will be able to drag the slider minimum to 1.

but why now in the first init when declaring the variables the sliders values are 0 ?

I tested now if i init all the 3 variables in the Update() to 1 then it will change them in the inspector to value 1. I thought if i init the variables in the top when declaring them they should be in the inspector already as first init at value 1 and not 0.

Comment: *Only if i will click now on the sliders and drag them then the slider itself will show* - sounds like there is an event to load/initialize the Sliders, before the click event in the Sliders event lifecycle.

Comment: I've tested your code and the sliders values were equal to 1. Are you sure you've not assigned a value (I mean 0) to them in some method (like `Start()`)? If you've done this, it has caused the problem because this script `executes always` including in edit mode.

Comment: @Abolfazl i edited the question with the full script another problem i'm facing is with the variable numberOfChildrenInLevel when the flag randomNumberOfChildren is true it's not generating random number the value of numberOfChildrenInLevel is 1 all the time and in the inspector i see the slider move back to 1 even if i changed it's value to 41 or 70 or any number it's moving back to 1. not sure why.

Comment: Because you have ExecuteAlways attribute on the script, numberOfChildrenInLevel will keep changing until the script stops.

Comment: Did you add the sliders before or after attaching the script to this object ?